# Split vertical for GNU screen in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, gnu-screen

In cygwin using GNU screen there isn't the vertical split (vsplit). How can i add the vsplit

Comment: version screen-4.0.3-7

Comment: Were you able to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news, the latest version of screen from git has now been packaged and released for Cygwin (version 4.1.0-20130513-1), and it includes the vertical split feature.  Just install the current version as usual from setup, and you should have it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a patch to add `vsplit` to gnu `screen`, and people have gotten it to run on cynwin (http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2010-08/msg00135.html).  You might be able to find a binary out there or you might need to compile it yourself.

Comment: Compiling does not seem to work right away as the maintainer of the cygwin screen mentioned that he has to patch some things [himself](http://old.nabble.com/where-to-get-the-vertical-split-patch--td31658495.html): `"The usual advice seems to be to check out the latest version of the screen source from git, which includes the vertical split capability. Unfortunately this doesn't work in Cygwin, because there's a large Cygwin-specific patch that I have to apply, that fails on the latest git source."`